# How to reveal vpn configuration password and username on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, vpn

[image]

My friend has a vpn that doesn't remember the secret and password of it in settings . How can we share that vpn config or maybe reveal it's password and secret keys ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see connected vpn details on macbook?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448737/how-to-see-connected-vpn-details-on-macbook)

Comment: @not2savvy I did ask that question also